# xpath: How to select only nearby parent siblings of current child node?

Tags: xpath

Im using xpath 1.0 and i want to select a siblings of a parent of a current child node.

The current node that im in is `<w:instrText>` and how can i get the parent sibling nodes `<w:r>` that only in range of `<!-- SELECT FROM HERE -->` and `<!-- SELECT TILL HERE -->`?

```
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val='en-US'/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>TEXT 1</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:t xml:space='preserve'> </w:t>
      </w:r>

      <!-- SELECT FROM HERE -->
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='begin'/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:instrText xml:space='preserve'> SOME DYNAMIC TEXT THAT CAN CHANGE </w:instrText> <!-- My cursor is here! -->
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='separate'/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='00E5783C'>
        <w:t>SOME DYNAMIC TEXT</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='end'/>
      </w:r>
      <!-- SELECT TILL HERE -->

      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='begin'/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:instrText xml:space='preserve'> SOME DYNAMIC TEXT THAT CAN CHANGE </w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='separate'/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='00E5783C'>
        <w:t>SOME DYNAMIC TEXT</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR='002D5530'>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType='end'/>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

This is what i tried but got only 3 nodes...

```
../preceding-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin'] | ../following-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end']
```

Comment: What patterns can be used to distinguish your desired range?  Does the range always start with a `w:r` containing a `w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin'`?  Does the range always end with `w:r` containing a `w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'`?  Do the `w:r/w:*` nodes always appear in the same order as shown here (fldchar, instrText, fldChar, t, fldChar)?

Comment: @DavidDenenberg 1st: YES; 2nd: YES; 3rd: YES; ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the limitations of XPath 1.0 and the assumption that the order of the sets of five `w:r` elements is consistent you could use a somewhat brute-force approach like:

```
(
  (../preceding-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin'])[last()],
  (../following-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='separate'])[position() = 1],
  (../following-sibling::w:r[w:t])[position() = 1],
  (../following-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'])[position() = 1]
)
```

Which is forming a sequence of four elements:

- the last of the preceding "begin" elements
- the first of the following "separate" elements
- the first of the following "t" elements (`w:r` containing a `w:t`)
- the first of the following "end" elements

If you also need to include the immediate parent of your context, then just add `..` or `parent::*` or `parent::w:r` to the sequence:

```
(
  (../preceding-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='begin'])[last()],
  ..,
  (../following-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='separate'])[position() = 1],
  (../following-sibling::w:r[w:t])[position() = 1],
  (../following-sibling::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType='end'])[position() = 1]
)
```

However, this may not be efficient if your input document is huge or performance is a significant factor.

If you are curious why your attempt returned three elements instead of two it is probably because you selected both "end" elements that were beyond the position of your context.  The answer here may not be precisely what you need, but I suspect the last()/position() predicate examples will set you in the right direction.

BTW, if you ever have the opportunity to use XQuery for something like this, it is a perfect use case for the XQuery 3 "tumbling window" syntax which makes it very easy to identify the boundaries of sibling groups and iterate over the groups.

Comment: With this xpath query i have 4 elements instead of 5

Comment: Do you expect the parent node too?  The question said “parent sibling”.

Comment: Updated the answer with guidance for including the immediate parent in the sequence of selected nodes.

Comment: BTW.. in my case the commas are not working... i united it with ```|```

Comment: I believe the sequence forming comma is supposed to be valid XPath 1.0 syntax, but I have also seen this kind of behavior where certain processors are not fully compliant.  The pipe character is a union operator.  It will definitely return the same nodes in this use case, but I am not sure if the order of the nodes is guaranteed to be preserved.